# Nginx - all domains redirect

Tags: nginx

I looked around to see NGINX configuration for ALL domains and sub-domain but I can only find configurations that are specified.

This is what I want to achieve

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name all;
    return 301 https://www.test.com$request_uri;
}
```

but then I don't want www.test.com forwarded, only anything else that doesn't match it, even if it is like x.test.com it should be forward too

how I can do it?

Comment: @Johan I think it's not a duplicate. The OP wants to redirect all **domains** (not **locations**) except one.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderAzarov, it's a valid point. I'll delete my comment to avoid confusion, but include the link I originally linked to, to keep context: [nginx: rewrite all except one location](https://serverfault.com/a/331601)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a separate `server` block for the domain you don't want to redirect. For example:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.test.com;
  # rest of configuration
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  return 301 https://www.test.com$request_uri;
}
```

---

BTW, you are redirecting to `https`. Then you need to `listen` not only 80, but 443 as well. I hope you have it working and left out for the question's simplicity. Otherwise, the documentation is [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen).

Comment: I will test it when I am home, so not defining server_name takes everything into account? Even if someone else create a domain example fakedomain.com and puts my ip address, it will redirect him to the www.test.com right?

Comment: Okay will post feedback here when I test it so it is useful for others. Thank you Alexander!

Comment: Nginx will serve the default unless explicitly told not to. Including https of the default if you only have http configured on your exception (and vice versa)....

Comment: Sorry couldnt post before but it is working, put it as solution. Thanks Alexander!